# Exception thrown when parsing seemingly correct time span

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

I am using the `TimeSpan.ParseExact` method to parse a time span. However, why does the following fail and throw an exception?

```
string time = "23:10:00";
string format = "HH:mm:ss";
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Judging from the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) article on MSDN, the format is correct for this input string. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't look like C++. Should it be tagged C# or CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You linked to the custom `DateTime` format specifiers - but you're not parsing to `DateTime`, you're parsing to `TimeSpan`, so you need the [custom `TimeSpan` format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) - which means using "hh" instead of "HH". Additionally, as per the documentation, you need to escape the colons - so you really want:

```
string format = @"hh\:mm\:ss";
```

I've validated that this works with your sample value.

Comment: Man, why do the format strings have to be different? This is going to cause serious issues in our code. Thanks again buddy.

Comment: @Steztric: It should only cause issues in your code if you're treating `TimeSpan` formats and `DateTime` formats as interchangeable. They're very different types, so you *should* be treating the formats differently :)