# Parse exact custom time format?

Tags: c#, timespan

I can't seem to get the custom format right for my `TimeSpan.ParseExact()`:

Time samples to be expected:

```
1:23:45.6
23:45.6
23:45
1:23:45
```

The string format I'm using:

```
string withTenthFormat = @"[%h\:]mm\:ss[\.%f]";
```

Trying to have hours and fractions of seconds optionally. However using this format and an `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` does lead to a `FormatException`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of the ability to specify optional parts like that in a custom format string. I suggest you use multiple format strings, and use the overload of `TimeSpan.ParseExact` that takes an array of formats.

```
string[] formats = { @"h\:mm\:ss\.FFF", @"mm\:ss\.FFF",
                     @"h\:mm\:ss", @"mm\:ss"};
string[] values = { "1:23:45.6", "23:45.6", "23:45", "1:23:45" };

foreach (string value in values)
{
    var parsed = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, formats,
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(parsed);
}
```

(I'm using `FFF` as the milliseconds specifier to allow you to express "1:23:45.67" as well. If you only *ever* want hundreds of milliseconds, `F` or `f` would be fine.)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead because it's more powerful:

```
string[] strings = new[] { "1:23:45.6", "23:45.6", "23:45", "1:23:45" };
string[] formats = new[] { "H:mm:ss.f", "H:mm.f", "H:mm", "H:mm:ss" };
TimeSpan[] timespans = strings
    .Select(str =>
    {
        TimeSpan? ts = null;
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            ts = dt.TimeOfDay;
        return ts;
    })
    .Where(ts => ts.HasValue)
    .Select(ts => ts.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://ideone.com/7Baa36)</kbd>

Comment: But it's not parsing what you're trying to parse - date and time handling is *much* simpler when you make sure you're always dealing with the type you're actually interested in. `TimeSpan.ParseExact` can work fine here.

Comment: Point taken. However, i keep the answer to show that you can also parse `TimeSpan`s with `DateTime.ParseExact` which supports much more formats, is [easier to use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12731600/284240) and is also available below .NET 4.

Comment: So long as you want to parse a value of less than 24 hours, of course. If you want to allow days it becomes trickier. And I agree that TimeSpan parsing in .NET is more finicky than it really should be.