# TimeSpan.ParseExact different format

Tags: c#, parsing, format, timespan

Different timespan format has been arrived to service side. Normally I m parsing like below:

```
stringTimeSpan = "P18DT5H"; 
TimeSpan.ParseExact((string)stringTimeSpan , "'P'd'DT'h'H'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

its ok. But sometimes it arrives as  "P1D" without hour and minute. only day.
So how can I use generic parse mecanism?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse exact custom time format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123747/parse-exact-custom-time-format)

Comment: Ok it works. I wrote wrong format .

Answer (score 0):

WhenI tried format array like below:

```
string[] formats = new[] { "'P'd'D'", "'P'd'DT'h'H'", "'P'd'DT'h'H'm'M'", "'P'd'DT'h'H''m'M's'S'" };
                mytimespan = TimeSpan.ParseExact((string)stringTimeSpan , formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it worked.